# OpenCV 2.4.11 Compilation For ROS ORB_SLAM2 Fails

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, cmake, ros

I am trying to get orb_slam2_ros to compile and it needed an OpenCV version higher than 2.3. I have 4.2.0 but it doesn't work but according to ROS, it has been tested to work on 2.4.11. Here is what I did:

- Download the source zip file.
- Extract it.
- Go into the directory and create a build folder.
- Go into the build folder and run `cmake ..`.
  There is gives me this:

```
    CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVDetectCXXCompiler.cmake:85 (list):
      list GET given empty list
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      CMakeLists.txt:84 (include)
    
    
    CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVDetectCXXCompiler.cmake:86 (list):
      list GET given empty list
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      CMakeLists.txt:84 (include)
    
    
    CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVDetectCXXCompiler.cmake:89 (math):
      math cannot parse the expression: "*100 + ": syntax error, unexpected
      exp_TIMES (1).
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      CMakeLists.txt:84 (include)
    
    
    -- Detected version of GNU GCC:  (ERROR)
    -- Found OpenEXR: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so
    -- checking for module 'gstreamer-video-1.0'
    --   package 'gstreamer-video-1.0' not found
    -- checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
    --   package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' not found
    -- checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
    --   package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' not found
    -- checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
    --   package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' not found
    -- checking for module 'gstreamer-base-0.10'
    --   package 'gstreamer-base-0.10' not found
    -- checking for module 'gstreamer-video-0.10'
    --   package 'gstreamer-video-0.10' not found
    -- checking for module 'gstreamer-app-0.10'
    --   package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' not found
    -- checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-0.10'
    --   package 'gstreamer-riff-0.10' not found
    -- checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10'
    --   package 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10' not found
    -- Looking for linux/videodev.h
    -- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
    -- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
    -- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
    -- Looking for sys/videoio.h
    -- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
    -- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h
    -- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - found
    -- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
    -- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
    -- 
    -- General configuration for OpenCV 2.4.11 =====================================
    --   Version control:               unknown
    -- 
    --   Platform:
    --     Host:                        Linux 5.8.0-41-generic x86_64
    --     CMake:                       3.16.3
    --     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    --     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
    --     Configuration:               Release
    -- 
    --   C/C++:
    --     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    --     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 9.3.0)
    --     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -ffunction-sections -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    --     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -ffunction-sections -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    --     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
    --     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -ffunction-sections -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    --     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -ffunction-sections -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    --     Linker flags (Release):
    --     Linker flags (Debug):
    --     Precompiled headers:         YES
    -- 
    --   OpenCV modules:
    --     To be built:                 core flann imgproc highgui features2d calib3d ml video legacy objdetect photo gpu ocl nonfree contrib stitching superres ts videostab
    --     Disabled:                    world
    --     Disabled by dependency:      -
    --     Unavailable:                 androidcamera dynamicuda java python viz
    -- 
    --   GUI: 
    --     QT:                          NO
    --     GTK+ 2.x:                    YES (ver 2.24.32)
    --     GThread :                    YES (ver 2.64.6)
    --     GtkGlExt:                    NO
    --     OpenGL support:              NO
    --     VTK support:                 NO
    -- 
    --   Media I/O: 
    --     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
    --     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver )
    --     PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.6.37)
    --     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.1.0)
    --     JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
    --     OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so (ver 2.3.0)
    -- 
    --   Video I/O:
    --     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
    --     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.5)
    --     FFMPEG:                      YES
    --       codec:                     YES (ver 58.54.100)
    --       format:                    YES (ver 58.29.100)
    --       util:                      YES (ver 56.31.100)
    --       swscale:                   YES (ver 5.5.100)
    --       gentoo-style:              YES
    --     GStreamer:                   NO
    --     OpenNI:                      NO
    --     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
    --     PvAPI:                       NO
    --     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
    --     UniCap:                      NO
    --     UniCap ucil:                 NO
    --     V4L/V4L2:                    Using libv4l1 (ver 1.18.0) / libv4l2 (ver 1.18.0)
    --     XIMEA:                       NO
    --     Xine:                        NO
    -- 
    --   Other third-party libraries:
    --     Use IPP:                     NO
    --     Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 3.3.7)
    --     Use TBB:                     NO
    --     Use OpenMP:                  NO
    --     Use GCD                      NO
    --     Use Concurrency              NO
    --     Use C=:                      NO
    --     Use Cuda:                    NO
    --     Use OpenCL:                  YES
    -- 
    --   OpenCL:
    --     Version:                     dynamic
    --     Include path:                /home/dragonros/Downloads/SLAM_DEPS/opencv-2.4.11/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    --     Use AMD FFT:                 NO
    --     Use AMD BLAS:                NO
    -- 
    --   Python:
    --     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2 (ver )
    -- 
    --   Java:
    --     ant:                         NO
    --     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include
    --     Java tests:                  NO
    -- 
    --   Documentation:
    --     Build Documentation:         NO
    --     Sphinx:                      NO
    --     PdfLaTeX compiler:           NO
    --     Doxygen:                     NO
    -- 
    --   Tests and samples:
    --     Tests:                       YES
    --     Performance tests:           YES
    --     C/C++ Examples:              NO
    -- 
    --   Install path:                  /usr/local
    -- 
    --   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/dragonros/Downloads/SLAM_DEPS/build
    -- -----------------------------------------------------------------
    -- 
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "/home/dragonros/Downloads/SLAM_DEPS/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    See also "/home/dragonros/Downloads/SLAM_DEPS/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Am I compiling it wrong? If not, how can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `opencv2.4.13/cmake/OpenCVDetectCXXCompiler.cmake` (not sure which line) `dumpversion` to `dumpfullversion`

Explanation is [that](https://answers.opencv.org/question/65548/cmake-error-at-cmakeopencvdetectcxxcompilercmake/)

> In gcc with higher version, dumpversion function can't get true full
> version number of compiler so that cmake progress will fail

*Recommendation*: On github, there plenty of refactored versions for both 4.2.0 and others. I recommend to upgrade to newer OpenCV versions for orb_slam_ros. Cmake lists and source files should be changed respectively.

Comment: Yes I found a version on GitHub that works https://github.com/appliedAI-Initiative/orb_slam_2_ros.